# ProcessNotifyRoutine and Minifilter

Tags: minifilter, wdm

*Sorry for my bad English* .I have 2 question . My question is about PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx. First question is : Can I use this routine inside MiniFilter driver. For Example I Create PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine in DriverEntry and inside CallbackFunction I do next operations. For Example with FltSendMessage I send executed process path to usermode app? If yes then what happen when new Process Created? Suppose Process A created and in minifilter driver I call FltSendMessage to send filepath usermode app and usermode app scan executable path , but while this minifilter driver waiting usermode ReplyMessage and new Process B created same time what happen in this situation? Actually I tested this code and it works well in usermode layer I call Sleep(5000) after I send ReplyMessage to kernel. And when new process created it sit waiting mode and executed after minifilter receive usermode reply message. Can it make problem(bsod) for any situation? if yes can I use any sync kernel object(guarded mutex spin or etc?)

2nd question: I created minifilter driver which spying when user try to open executable path) it works well.I need to get filename in PreCreate(with FltGetFileNameInformation) and send it usermode app.But there is small problem?When user try to open filename there are multiple pre callback with same filename I know system also use this file but how can i prevent this. I readed about stream context but I dont know which type i must use for same filename(stream context or stream handle context)?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: hello sorry what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, **YES** you can use process notify routines in a minifilter and **YES** you can call FltSendMessage from the process notify callback.
If 2 or more processes are created in the same time, nothing special really happens, your callback will be called at the same time (one per processor suppose) for all of the processes ( depending how many processors you have). All you need to synchronize are you own internal list/structures as your own queries/manipulations could race on them as processes are being created/terminated.

For your second question I would suggest to not do much processing in PRE Create rather wait for POST Create and do your queries there because the FileObject does not represent an open file at that point. The file might not even exist.
In PostCreate if you decide to "block" the Create/Open simply use FltCancelFileOpen and set the IoStatus to STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. Querying the name in Pre or basically doing stuff in Pre is much more inefficient.
For the context question it depends what you need. I am suspecting you first need to understand better what is the difference between a STREAM and a STREAM HANDLE context.
As this is not the point of the question I would suggest you go through the documentation as this will be very important for your design decision in your filter.